ROS2 on Windows cannot open serial port when node is started from launch file
I am running ROS2 Foxy on a Windows 10 machine. I have a python node in a package that uses pyserial to read data on a COM port.

When I run the node from command line as such, everything works properly

C:\dev\rosnodes>ros2 run data_parser minimal
[INFO] [1726063643.314530800] [minimal_serial_node]: Initializing MinimalSerialNode
[INFO] [1726063643.316167400] [minimal_serial_node]: ok now
[INFO] [1726063643.320032900] [minimal_serial_node]: Serial port opened successfully



When I start the node from a launch file it just hangs: I only get this log message but no other log messages from the node indicating it has started properly.

C:\dev\rosnodes>ros2 launch data_parser minimal_launch.py
[INFO] [launch]: All log files can be found below C:\Users\<MY_USERNAME>\.ros\log\2024-09-11-16-05-54-658667-sip10-9096
[INFO] [launch]: Default logging verbosity is set to INFO
[INFO] [minimal.EXE-1]: process started with pid [6388]
<after I press CRTL+C>
[WARNING] [launch]: user interrupted with ctrl-c (SIGINT)
[ERROR] [minimal.EXE-1]: process has died [pid 6388, exit code 3221225786, cmd 'C:\dev\rosnodes\install\data_parser\lib\data_parser\minimal.EXE --ros-args -r __node:=minimal'].
[minimal.EXE-1] [INFO] [1726063555.208005100] [minimal]: Initializing MinimalSerialNode

This is my node:
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
import serial
import time
class MinimalSerialNode(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('minimal_serial_node')
        self.get_logger().info('Initializing MinimalSerialNode')
        self.get_logger().info('ok now')


    #     self.timer = self.create_timer(3.0, self.timerExpired)
   
    # def timerExpired(self):
        try:
            self.ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600, timeout=1)
            self.get_logger().info('Serial port opened successfully')
        except Exception as e:
            self.get_logger().error(f'Failed to open serial port: {str(e)}')


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = MinimalSerialNode()
    rclpy.spin(node)
    node.destroy_node()
    rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


and this is my launch file
import os
import sys
import yaml


from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory


from launch_ros.actions import Node


from launch import LaunchDescription


def generate_launch_description():


    # handy paths
   
    pacakge_path = os.path.realpath(get_package_share_directory('data_parser'))
    processes=[]
   
    # start the serial node
    minimal_serial_node = Node(
       package= 'data_parser',
       executable='minimal',
       name='minimal',
    )
    processes.append(minimal_serial_node)


    return LaunchDescription(processes)

This node and launch file work completely fine on Ubuntu, and in a Ubuntu container on Windows. All other nodes I have work fine on Windows, only the serial port opening seems to be problematic.
Things I have tried that make no difference:

Running this with Administrator privileges
Different launch file syntax (ExecuteProcess)

Any help is super appreciated!!!
